# Weird performance effects from nearby dependent stores in a pointer-chasing loop on IvyBridge. Adding an extra load speeds it up?

Tags: assembly, x86, micro-optimization, microbenchmark, micro-architecture

First I have the below setup on an IvyBridge, I will insert measuring payload code in the commented location. The first 8 bytes of `buf` store the address of `buf` itself, I use this to create loop-carried dependency:

```
section .bss
align   64
buf:    resb    64

section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov rcx,         1000000000
    mov qword [buf], buf
    mov rax,         buf
loop:
    ; I will insert payload here
    ; as is described below 

    dec rcx
    jne loop

    xor rdi,    rdi
    mov rax,    60
    syscall
```

### case 1:

I insert into the payload location:

```
mov qword [rax+8],  8
mov rax,            [rax]
```

`perf` shows the loop is 5.4c/iter. It's somewhat comprehensible, because L1d latency is 4 cycle.

### case 2:

I reverse the order of these two instruction:

```
mov rax,            [rax]
mov qword [rax+8],  8
```

The result suddenly becomes 9c/iter. I don't understand why. Because the first instruction of the next iteration doesn't depend on the second instruction of the current iteration, this setting shouldn't be different with case 1.

I also used IACA tool to analyze these two cases statically, but the tool is unreliable, because it predicts the same result 5.71c/iter for both cases, which contradicts to the experiment.

### case 3:

Then I insert an irrelevant `mov` instruction to case 2:

```
mov rax,            [rax]
mov qword [rax+8],  8
mov rbx,            [rax+16]
```

Now the result becomes 6.8c/iter. But how can an irrelevant `mov` inserted boost the speed from 9c/iter to 6.8c/iter?

The IACA tool predicts wrong result as in the previous case, it shows 5.24c/iter.

I'm now totally confused, how to comprehend the above results?

### Edit for more info:

In case 1 and 2, there is an address `rax+8`. The same results remain for case 1 and 2 if `rax+8` is changed to `rax+16` or `rax+24`. But something surprising happens when it is changed to `rax+32`: case 1 becomes 5.3c/iter, case 2 suddenly becomes 4.2c/iter.

### Edit for more `perf` events:

```
$ perf stat -ecycles,ld_blocks_partial.address_alias,int_misc.recovery_cycles,machine_clears.count,uops_executed.stall_cycles,resource_stalls.any ./a.out
```

case 1 for `[rax+8]`:

```
 5,429,070,287      cycles                                                        (66.53%)
         6,941      ld_blocks_partial.address_alias                                     (66.75%)
       426,528      int_misc.recovery_cycles                                      (66.83%)
        17,117      machine_clears.count                                          (66.84%)
 2,182,476,446      uops_executed.stall_cycles                                     (66.63%)
 4,386,210,668      resource_stalls.any                                           (66.41%)
```

case 2 for `[rax+8]`:

```
 9,018,343,290      cycles                                                        (66.59%)
         8,266      ld_blocks_partial.address_alias                                     (66.73%)
       377,824      int_misc.recovery_cycles                                      (66.76%)
        10,159      machine_clears.count                                          (66.76%)
 7,010,861,225      uops_executed.stall_cycles                                     (66.65%)
 7,993,995,420      resource_stalls.any                                           (66.51%)
```

case 3 for `[rax+8]`:

```
 6,810,946,768      cycles                                                        (66.69%)
         1,641      ld_blocks_partial.address_alias                                     (66.73%)
       223,062      int_misc.recovery_cycles                                      (66.73%)
         7,349      machine_clears.count                                          (66.74%)
 3,618,236,557      uops_executed.stall_cycles                                     (66.58%)
 5,777,653,144      resource_stalls.any                                           (66.53%)
```

case 2 for `[rax+32]`:

```
 4,202,233,246      cycles                                                        (66.68%)
         2,969      ld_blocks_partial.address_alias                                     (66.68%)
       149,308      int_misc.recovery_cycles                                      (66.68%)
         4,522      machine_clears.count                                          (66.68%)
 1,202,497,606      uops_executed.stall_cycles                                     (66.64%)
 3,179,044,737      resource_stalls.any                                           (66.64%)
```

Comment: Regarding case 1, the memory write takes only 1 cycle to execute (both STD and STA uops each take 1 cycle). The read takes 4 cycles though, so 5.4c/iter makes sense. Regarding case 3, the third `mov` instruction results in contention on the AGU units, so performance should be a little worse than that of case 1, so 6.8c/iter makes sense. I can't think of an obvious explanation to case 2, so we have to investigate more. For example, add `mov qword [rax+8],  8` just before  (outside) the loop and see how that changes performance. Another thing you can try is aligning the loop on 32-byte boundary.

Comment: @HadiBrais Adding a `mov` before the loop or align the loop doesn't make difference. But the offset 8 in `[rax+8]` might play an important role here, see my edit.

Comment: Interesting. Does your CPU support hyperthreading? Make sure that hyperthreading is disabled. Now we need to measure the following performance events for each case: `LD_BLOCKS_PARTIAL.ADDRESS_ALIAS`, `INT_MISC.RECOVERY_CYCLES`, `MACHINE_CLEARS.COUNT`, `UOPS_EXECUTED.STALL_CYCLES`, `L1D_BLOCKS.BANK_CONFLICT_CYCLES`, and `RESOURCE_STALLS.ANY`. Of course we need also the unhalted cycle count (called `cycles` in perf). Consult the performance events manual to determine the event codes for these events.

Comment: On Skylake case1 = case2 = ~4.4 cycles per iter, regardless of changing +8 to +256 displacement, for example.  We do know that there are big differences in how the front-end will feed this loop to the OoO core on IvB vs. SKL, so I wonder if that's significant.  You'd expect not with a loop that runs at less than ~1/4 of front-end throughput.  On IvB it runs from the loop buffer with each iteration issuing together, so that's probably connected with why reordering could make a difference.

Comment: Cache-bank conflicts probably aren't a factor for `+8`, but could be for `+128`.  But `+32` is still within the same line, writing a different bank, and not crossing a line or bank boundary because `buf` is aligned.

Comment: I *can* repro the speedup with case 3 on SKL, though.  From 4.4 to 4.0 cycles per iteration.  (But HSW and later have a store AGU on port 7, so it never conflicts with loads...)  I don't understand why any of the version would run slower than 4.0 cycles per iter (L1d pointer-chasing latency).  The specific latency numbers you see look a *lot* like the [Is there a penalty when base+offset is in a different page than the base?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52351397) non-optimized (5c) and the retry case (9c on HSW (and earlier?))), but I don't know why that would happen.

Comment: Changing the store address to `[rel buf+8]` makes case 2 run at 4c per iter on SKL.  The CPU can run the store-address uops ahead of time, if the front end runs ahead at all, and more quickly detect that the load and store don't overlap.  I think I've read that Intel CPUs use dynamic prediction for memory disambiguation.  (i.e. there's a predictor cache that remembers that this load didn't need store-forwarding.)  If that's really true, the only effect of making the address dependent is that the store-address uops can't run as early.  (I also tried with `abs buf` so it could micro-fuse: same).

Comment: @HadiBrais Disable or enable hyperthreading doesn't make difference :\

Comment: @PeterCordes I also tested `[rel buf+8]` on IvyBridge, all cases become 4c/iter, so it's related to the dependent stores. Out of curiosity, how frequent do this sort of microarch oddity happen in practice? This code looks so simple, for more complex real code, I'm wondering whether it's really possible to predict number of cycles in the critical part.

Comment: Imperfect scheduling or whatever does sometimes happen with pure ALU loops that have interlocking dependencies, but usually forking off short independent chains from a loop-carried chain doesn't hurt throughput.  Stores and loads make things complicated.  Memory disambiguation is hard, and x86 has to give the illusion of following strong memory ordering semantics while actually executing aggressively out of order so there's a lot of mem HW.  Predicting throughput in real code that loops over an array or two usually works out pretty accurately, even loading from one and storing to the other.

Comment: It would helpful if you could measure the performance counters I mentioned in my earlier comment so we can get additional hints to proceed confidently with the analysis. I don't have access to an IvB system at the moment so I can't run the experiments myself.

Comment: @HadiBrais Some results added.

Comment: My results on Haswell are different from IvB and SK, but also equally interesting. Case1 = case2 = 8.4c/iter and case 3 = 8.9c/iter. `STALLS_LDM_PENDING` is equal to `CYCLES_NO_EXECUTE` =  6c, suggesting that the effective impact of the load latency on performance is 6 our of the 8.4c and that the load latency is at least 6c. The `UOPS_EXECUTED_PORT.PORT_X` events show that `PORT_2`+`PORT_3`+`PORT_7` = 5B uops, but the expected value is 2B. However, `PORT_4` is 1B as expected. For some reason, the load uop is being replayed.

Comment: However, if I change `[rax+8]` to `[rax+64]` or larger displacements, case1 and case2 become 4.3c/iter and `PORT_2`+`PORT_3`+`PORT_7` = 2B as expected.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think that on HSW, a load and store to the same cache line cannot be performed in parallel. If there is a non-overlapping load and a store (to be committed) to the same line, the memory unit will choose one and issue it and the other will have to wait until it completes. For example, it may prioritizes loads over stores unless the store buffer is full or something. My results suggest that `STALLS_LDM_PENDING` might be capturing this effect. The OP's results suggest that this issue might exist on IvB but with different performance impact...

Comment: ...Your results suggest that this issue doesn't exist on SKL. AFAIK, the manual doesn't say anything about whether a non-overlapping load and store *to the same line* can be performed in parallel for any of the micoarchitectures. It just talks about two loads to the same line or bank. My results also show that the number of uops dispatched to ports 247 is larger than what is expected, which is probably because the scheduler thinks that the load will take 4c  but it actually takes longer because it gets blocked by a store to the same line, so dependent uops need to be re-dispatched (replayed).

Comment: I came up with another analysis method to reach essentially the same conclusion, but is much easier.

Comment: @PeterCordes - yes, memory disambiguation uses a predictor. I put the details of how it works on Skylake [here](https://github.com/travisdowns/uarch-bench/wiki/Memory-Disambiguation-on-Skylake) but I suspect it is similar for earlier arches too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tl;DR:** For these three cases, a penalty of a few cycles is incurred when performing a load and store at the same time. The load latency is on the critical path in all of the three cases, but the penalty is different in different cases. Case 3 is about a cycle higher than case 1 due to the additional load.

---

**Analysis Method 1: Using stall performance events**

I was able to reproduce your results for the all of the three cases on IvB and SnB. The numbers I got are within 2% of your numbers. The number of cycles it takes to execute a single iteration of case 1, 2, and 4 is 5.4, 8.9, and 6.6, respectively.

Let's start with the frontend. The `LSD.CYCLES_4_UOPS` and `LSD.CYCLES_3_UOPS` performance events show that basically all the uops are issued from the LSD. In addition, these events together with `LSD.CYCLES_ACTIVE` show that in every cycle in which the LSD is not stalled, 3 uops are issued in cases 1 and 2 and 4 uops are issued in case 3. In other words, as expected, the uops of every iteration are issued together in the same group in a single cycle.

In all of the following relations, the "=~" sign means that the difference is within 2%. I'll start with the following empirical observation:

`UOPS_ISSUED.STALL_CYCLES` + `LSD.CYCLES_ACTIVE` =~ `cycles`

Note that the LSD event counts on SnB need to be adjusted as discussed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54156499/why-jnz-requires-2-cycles-to-complete-in-an-inner-loop).

We also have the following relations:

case 1: `UOPS_ISSUED.STALL_CYCLES` =~ `RESOURCE_STALLS.ANY` =~ 4.4c/iter
case 2: `UOPS_ISSUED.STALL_CYCLES` =~ `RESOURCE_STALLS.ANY` =~ 7.9c/iter
case 3: `UOPS_ISSUED.STALL_CYCLES` =~ `RESOURCE_STALLS.ANY` =~ 5.6c/iter

This means that the reason for the issue stalls is because one or more required resources in the backend are not available. Therefore, we can confidently eliminate the whole frontend from consideration. In cases 1 and 2, that resource is the RS. In case 3, stalls due to the RS constitute about 20% of all resource stalls<sup>1</sup>.

Let's focus now on case 1. There are a total of 4 unfused domain uops: 1 load uop, 1 STA, 1 STD, and 1 dec/jne. The load and STA uops depend on the previous load uop. Whenever the LSD issues a group of uops, the STD and jump uops can be dispatched in the next cycle, so the next cycle will not cause an execution stall event. However, the earliest point where the load and STA uops can be dispatched is in the same cycle in the which the load result is written back. The correlation between `CYCLES_NO_EXECUTE` and `STALLS_LDM_PENDING` indicates that the reason why there would be no uops ready for execution is because all of the uops that are in the RS are waiting for the L1 to service pending load requests. Specifically, half of the uops in the RS are load uops and the other half are STAs and they are all waiting for the load of the respective previous iteration to complete. `LSD.CYCLES_3_UOPS` shows that the LSD waits until there are at least 4 free entries in the RS, only then it issues a group of uops that constitute a full iteration. In the next cycle, two of these uops will be dispatched, thereby freeing 2 RS entries<sup>2</sup>. The other will have to wait for the load they depend on to complete. Most probably the loads complete in program order. Therefore, the LSD waits until the STA and load uops of the oldest iteration that is yet to be executed leave the RS. Thus, `UOPS_ISSUED.STALL_CYCLES` + 1 =~ the average load latency<sup>3</sup>. We can conclude that the average load latency in case 1 is 5.4c. Most of this applies to case 2, except for one difference, as I'll explain shortly.

Since the uops in each iteration form a dependency chain, we also have:

`cycles` =~ the average load latency.

Hence:

`cycles` =~ `UOPS_ISSUED.STALL_CYCLES` + 1 =~ the average load latency.

In case 1, the average load latency is 5.4c. We know that the best-case latency of the L1 cache is 4c, so there is a load latency penalty of 1.4c. But why is the effective load latency not 4c?

The scheduler will predict that the load on which the uops depend will complete within some constant latency and so it will schedule them to be dispatched accordingly. If the load takes more time than that for any reason (such as an L1 miss), the uops will be dispatched but the load result has not arrived yet. In this case, the uops will be replayed and the number of dispatched uops will be larger than the total number of issued uops.

The load and STA uops can only be dispatched to port 2 or 3. The events `UOPS_EXECUTED_PORT.PORT_2` and `UOPS_EXECUTED_PORT.PORT_3` can be used to count the number of uops dispatched to port 2 and 3, respectively.

case 1: `UOPS_EXECUTED_PORT.PORT_2` + `UOPS_EXECUTED_PORT.PORT_3` =~ 2uops/iter
case 2: `UOPS_EXECUTED_PORT.PORT_2` + `UOPS_EXECUTED_PORT.PORT_3` =~ 6uops/iter
case 3: `UOPS_EXECUTED_PORT.PORT_2` + `UOPS_EXECUTED_PORT.PORT_3` =~ 4.2uops/iter

In case 1, the total number of AGU uops dispatched is exactly equal to the number of AGU uops retired; there are no replays. So the scheduler never mispredicts. In case 2, there is on average 2 replays per AGU uop, which means that the scheduler mispredicts twice on average per AGU uop. Why are there mispredictions in case 2 but not in case 1?

The scheduler will replay uops dependent on a load for any of the following reasons:

- L1 cache miss.
- Memory disambiguation misprediction.
- Memory consistency violation.
- L1 cache hit, but there is L1-L2 traffic.
- Virtual page number misprediction.
- Some other (undocumented) reasons.

The first 5 reasons can be definitively ruled out using the corresponding performance events. Patrick Fay (Intel) [says](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/280663) the following:

> Lastly yes, there are 'a few' idle cycles when switching between a
>   load and a store. I'm told not to be more specific than 'a few'.
>   ...
>   SNB can read and write different banks at the same cycle.

I find these statements, perhaps intentionally, a little ambiguous. The first statement suggests that a load and store to the L1 can never fully overlap. The second one suggests that a load and store can be performed in the same cycle only if there are to different banks. Although being to different banks may neither be a necessary nor sufficient condition. But one thing is for sure, if there are concurrent load and store requests, the load (and the store) can be delayed for one or more cycles. This explains the average 1.4c penalty on the load latency in case 1.

There is a difference between case 1 and case 2. In case 1, the STA and load uops that depend on the same load uop are issued together in the same cycle. On the other hand, in case 2, the STA and load uops that depend on the same load uop belong to two different issue groups. The issue stall time per iteration would be essentially equal to the time it takes to sequentially execute one load and retire one store. The contribution of each operation can be estimated using `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_LDM_PENDING`. It takes one cycle to execute the STA uop so the store can retire in the cycle that immediately follows the one in which the STA is dispatched.

The average load latency is `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_LDM_PENDING` + 1 cycle (the cycle in which the load is dispatched) + 1 cycle (the cycle in the which the jump uop is dispatched). We need to add 2 cycles to `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_LDM_PENDING` because there are no execution stalls in these cycles yet they constitute a fraction of the total load latency. This is equal to 6.8 + 2 = 8.8 cycles =~ `cycles`.

During the execution of the first dozen (or so) iterations, a jump and STD uops will be allocated in the RS every cycle. These will be always be dispatched for execution in the cycle that follows the issue cycle. At some point, the RS will get full and all of the entries that have not been dispatched yet will be STA and load uops that are waiting for the load uops of the respective previous iterations to complete (writeback their results). So the allocator will stall until there are enough free RS entries to issue a whole iteration. Let's assume that the oldest load uop has written back its result at cycle `T` + 0. I'll refer to the iteration to which that load uop belongs as the current iteration. The following sequence of events will occur:

At cycle `T` + 0: Dispatch the STA uop of the current iteration and the load uop of the next iteration. There is no allocation in this cycle because there aren't enough RS entries. This cycle gets counted as an allocation stall cycle but not as an execution stall cycle.

At cycle `T` + 1: The STA uop completes execution and the store retires. The uops of the next iteration to be allocated are allocated. This cycle gets counted as an execution stall cycle but not as an allocation stall cycle.

At cycle `T` + 2: The jump and STD uops that were just allocated get dispatched. This cycle gets counted as an allocation stall cycle but not as an execution stall cycle.

At cycles `T` + 3 to `T` + 3 + `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_LDM_PENDING` - 2: All of these cycles are counted as both execution and allocation stall cycles. Note that there are `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_LDM_PENDING` - 1 cycles here.

Therefore, `UOPS_ISSUED.STALL_CYCLES` should be equal to 1 + 0 + 1 + `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_LDM_PENDING` - 1. Let's check: 7.9 = 1+0+1+6.8-1.

Following the reasoning on case 1, `cycles` should be equal to `UOPS_ISSUED.STALL_CYCLES` + 1 = 7.9 + 1 =~ the actual measured `cycles`. The penalty incurred when performing a load and store in at the same time is 3.6c higher than in case 1. It is as if the load is waiting for a store get committed. I think this also explains why there are replays in the case 2 but not in case 1.

In case 3, there are 1 STD, 1 STA, 2 loads, and 1 jump. The uops of a single iteration can all be allocated in one cycle because the IDQ-RS bandwidth is 4 fused uops per cycle. The uops get unfused on entrance to the RS. The 1 STD require 1 cycle to be dispatched. The jump also takes 1 cycle. There are three AGU uops but only 2 AGU ports. So it takes 2 cycles (compared to 1 in case 1 and 2) to dispatch the AGU uops. The group of AGU uops dispatched will be one of the following:

- The second load uop and the STA uop of the same iteration. These are dependent on the first load uop of the same iteration. Both AGU ports are used.
- The first load uop of the next iteration can be dispatched in the next cycle. This depends on the load of the previous iteration. Only one of the two AGU ports is used.

Since it takes one more cycle to free enough RS entries to accommodate an entire issue group, `UOPS_ISSUED.STALL_CYCLES` + 1 - 1 = `UOPS_ISSUED.STALL_CYCLES` =~ the average load latency =~ 5.6c, which is very close to that of case 1. The penalty is about 1.6c. This explains why, in case 3 compared to case 1 and 2, each AGU uop is dispatched 1.4 times on average.

Again, since it takes on more cycle to free enough RS entries to accommodate an entire issue group:

`cycles` =~ the average load latency + 1 = 6.6c/iter, which actually exactly matches `cycles` as measured on my system.

A detailed analysis similar to that one on case 2 can be done on case 3 as well. In case 3, the execution of the STA is overlapped with latency of the second load. The latencies of both loads are also mostly overlapped.

I don't know why the penalties are different in the different cases. We would need to know how the L1D cache is exactly designed. Anyway, I feel confident enough that there is a penalty of "a few idle cycles" on the load latency (and the store latency) to post this answer.

---

**Footnotes**

(1) The other 80% of time is spent stalling on the load matrix. This structure is barely mentioned in the manual. It is used to specify dependencies between uops and load uops. It is [estimated](http://www.maqao.org/publications/papers/UFS.pdf) to have 32 entries on SnB and IvB. There is no documented performance event that can exclusively count stalls on the LM. All of the documented resource stall events are zero. In case 3, there are 3 out 5 uops per iteration that depend on the previous load, so most probably the LM will be filled before any of the other structures. The "effective" number of RS entries is estimated to be around 51 and 48 on IvB and SnB, respectively.

(2) I might have made a harmless simplification here. See [Is it possible for the RESOURCE_STALLS.RS event to occur even when the RS is not completely full?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656695/is-it-possible-for-the-resource-stalls-rs-event-to-occur-even-when-the-rs-is-not).

(3) It may be helpful to create a visualization of the uop flow through the pipeline to see how this all fits together. You can use a simple load chain as a reference. This is easy for case 1, but difficult for case 2 due to replay.

---

**Analysis Method 2: Using the load latency performance monitoring facility**

I came up with another method to analyze the code. This method is much easier but less accurate. However, it does essentially lead us to the same conclusion.

The alternative method is based on the `MEM_TRANS_RETIRED.LOAD_LATENCY_*` performance events. These events are special in the sense that they can only be counted at the **p**recise level (See: [PERF STAT does not count memory-loads but counts memory-stores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466697/perf-stat-does-not-count-memory-loads-but-counts-memory-stores)).

For example, `MEM_TRANS_RETIRED.LOAD_LATENCY_GT_4` counts the number of loads whose latency is larger than 4 core cycles of a "randomly" selected sample of all executed loads. The latency is measured as follows. The cycle in which the load is dispatched for the first time is the first cycle that is considered as part of the latency of the load. The cycle in which the load result is written back is the last cycle that is considered as part of the latency. Hence, replays are accounted for. Also, starting with SnB (at least), all loads have latencies larger than 4 cycles according to this definition. The minimum latency threshold that is currently supported is 3 cycles.

```
Case 1
Lat Threshold  | Sample Count
 3             | 1426934
 4             | 1505684
 5             | 1439650
 6             | 1032657      << Drop 1
 7             |   47543      << Drop 2
 8             |   57681
 9             |   60803
10             |   76655
11             |     <10      << Drop 3

Case 2
Lat Threshold  | Sample Count
 3             | 1532028
 4             | 1536547
 5             | 1550828
 6             | 1541661
 7             | 1536371
 8             | 1537337
 9             | 1538440
10             | 1531577
11             |     <10      << Drop

Case 3
Lat Threshold  | Sample Count
 3             | 2936547
 4             | 2890162
 5             | 2921158
 6             | 2468704      << Drop 1
 7             | 1242425      << Drop 2
 8             | 1238254
 9             | 1249995
10             | 1240548
11             |     <10      << Drop 3
```

It's critical to understand that these numbers represents the number of loads of the randomly selected sample of all loads. For example, of the total size of the sample of all loads is 10 million and only 1 million of these has a latency larger than the specified threshold, then the measured value is 1 million. However, the total number of executed loads could be 1 billion. Therefore, the absolute values are not very meaningful themselves. What really matters is the pattern across different thresholds.

In case 1, there are three significant drops in the number of loads whose latency is larger than a specific threshold. We can deduce that loads whose latency is equal to or smaller than 6 cycles are the most common, loads whose latency is equal to or smaller than 7 cycles but larger than 6 cycles are the second most common, and most other loads have a latency between 8-11 cycles.

we already know that the minimum latency is 4 cycles. Given these numbers, it's reasonable to estimate the average load latency to be somewhere between 4 and 6 cycles, but closer to 6 than 4. We know from Method 1 that the average load latency is actually 5.4c. So we can make a fairly good estimation using these numbers.

In case 2, we can deduce that most loads have a latency that is smaller than or equal to 11 cycles. The average load latency is probably also much larger than 4, given the consistency in the measured number of loads across a wide range of latency thresholds. So it's between 4 and 11, but closer to 11 than 4. We know from Method 1 that the average load latency is actually 8.8c, which is close to any reasonable estimation based on these numbers.

Case 3 is similar to case 1 and in fact they actual average load latency determined using Method 1 is almost the same for these two cases.

Making measurements using `MEM_TRANS_RETIRED.LOAD_LATENCY_*` is easy and such analysis can be done by someone with little knowledge about the microarchitecture.

Comment: Do we know if STD uops actually depend on STA uops, or if they can run in either order / in parallel?  It would make sense if STA has to reserve a space in the store buffer for STD, presumably making the design simpler.  (And that makes more sense than having the dependency go the other way, because you want to detect overlap / store-forwarding before store-data is ready.)  But do we know for sure?  The scheduler or allocator could choose a store-buffer entry for both to use, instead of requiring any forwarding of a result from STA to STD.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes we know for sure that STD and STA can be dispatched in any order. The allocation has already been done in the allocation stage. This is mentioned in multiple (old) Intel documents and can be proven experimentally.

Comment: Ah, I was trying to read quickly through parts of this dense answer that I expected I already understood, and missed how you were explaining this. 
So like I expected, STD and jump uops can dispatch right after they issue, and it's only STA and load uops where you're talking about "the current iteration".  I thought you were saying that STD uops were waiting for STA uops of the same iteration, but on more careful reading that's not what you're saying.  Possibly adding more words like "oldest STA" and "just-allocated STD/jump" would help future readers keep track of what's going on.

Comment: I'm not quite following the high level conclusion. Most of these architectures can sustain 1 load and 1 store per cycle, which implies that there is not always a replay of the load when they try to execute in the same cycle: indeed in that scenario they are _always_ executed in the same cycle. So there is not some general problem with loads and stores. Similarly, there can't be a delay of a "few cycles" when switching between loads and stores, since again you can execute 1 and 1 _every_ cycle, which is inconsistent with any delay at all (if delay means cycles where L1 can't do anything).

Comment: I think the key is the pointer chasing, and the special 4-cycle pointer chasing optimization. We know this optimization only applies when the virtual page is predicted correctly, and that it also works if there is no intervening ALU op modifying the address. It is entirely possible that it only works when consecutive loads go to the _same_ port (p2 or p3), since the incoming load result may have to feed back immediately into the AGU. Now in the case that there is a competing store operation maybe it uses the AGU instead and the optimization breaks, resulting in the 9 cycle replay.

Comment: Or perhaps the problem is that the store and subsequent load are both waiting for the load result. In the 4-cycle pointer chasing case maybe the load result isn't ready to broadcast on the bypass network in the optimized 4-cycle path, so it has to taken an extra cycle, which breaks the scheduler's prediction of 4 cycles? Well those both have various problems, such as why the offset matters. I didn't find the details of exactly which offsets show the behavior?

Comment: @Hadi I liked the list "The scheduler will replay uops dependent on a load for any of the following reasons" - where did you find it, or have you collected it yourself from various sources?

Comment: @BeeOnRope I think the answer conclusively shows that the throughput is low mainly because the load latency is high, and that the load latency is high because the store incurs a penalty of a few cycles on the load. However, as you pointed out, the answer doesn't explain why or when this penalty may occur. We have empirically determined that the addresses of the load and store can affect this penalty. So yes, it's possible to perform one store and load per cycle, but not always. Your 2end and 3rd comments...

Comment: ...seem to attempt to explain the *why*, which suggests that you are convinced that this penalty exists, but your first comment seems to be contesting this, so I'm a little confused. But like you said, it's not like there is a general problem that applies to every load and store, but there is definitely a problem other than ones I've listed. I made the list myself based on my experiments in the past on pre-SKL microarchs. Regarding the "why" and "when", more work needs to be done, which I have not (yet).

Comment: My first comment was specifically about your first sentence: "A penalty of a few cycles is incurred when performing a load and store at the same time". I took this as a general statement. However, it is not true that a (replay) penalty is usually incurred in this case, in fact this is fairly unusual which is why the effect in this question is special to the point that I first learned about it here. Perhaps you meant this in a less general way such as "In this specific case, the store and load interfere in such a way as to cause the load to replay and increase the latency...".

Comment: I agree with you that the load latency is longer, but the original questions already showed that: the benchmark is effectively a _measurement_ of the load latency. So saying the pointer chasing loop takes X cycles because the load latency in this case is X, isn't saying much, is it? The real question is why the latency is extended - and we know the likely 1st level answer: a replay occurs. So the 2nd question is "why does the replay occur"? The rest of analysis, while interesting, mostly just shows that nothing super weird is going on outside of the replay: what you see is what you get...

Comment: @BeeOnRope I don't about you, but when I first read question, I was surprised to see that the loop throughput is 5.4c, 9c, and 6.8 for the three different cases. It's not obvious at all (at least to me) where these numbers are coming from and what the effective load latency is in each of the cases and how it impacts overall perf. These numbers are weird for such loops. My analysis shows that all the cases are actually bounded by the load latency but it's just that the latency is larger than expected (4c) and varies. As to the "why", we can...

Comment: ...guess but we cannot know for sure without access to implementation details. Consider a similar question on a simple load loop with a throughput of 4c, do you expect from the answer to explain *why* the load latency is 4c? We can also make a number of good guesses, but we cannot know for sure without access to implementation details. If you have an empirical method that we can use to answer the "why" question with high confidence, I'm all ears....

Comment: On the other hand, we can answer the "when" question by running a sufficient number of experiments. Anyway, I'll clarify that specific sentence at the top of the answer.

Comment: Yes, I was surprised at the numbers: I would expect all these loops to execute in 4 cycles per iteration. I think the average "effective" load latency here is relatively obvious: it is exactly the iteration time of each benchmark. You don't need any deep analysis to understand that because the benchmark is essentially the canonical benchmark for load latency (a series of dependent loads). So saying that the load latency is 5.4c for a test that takes 5.4c cycles to perform a series of dependent loads, isn't saying much: the only interesting part is _why_?

Comment: For a simple loop that actually takes 4c, the answer would be simple: this is the known and documented load latency on Intel, and this type of loop is bound by load latency, and so everything is exactly as expected. It is cases where the load latency is 5.4c or 9c or whatever, I think the question is implicitly "why is 5.4c or 9c and not 4"?