# reorder buffer problem (computer architecture Udacity course)

Tags: cpu-architecture

can someone explains to me why the issue time for instruction I5 is cycle 6 and not cycle 5 according to the solution manual provided to that problem.

Notes: 1) the problem and its published solution is mentioned below 2) this problem is part of the problem set for the computer architecture course on Udacity

> problem:
>
> Using Tomasulo's algorithm, for each instruction in the following
> sequence determine when (in which cycle, counting from the start) it
> issues, begins execution, and writes its result to the CDB. Assume
> that the result of an instruction can be written in the cycle after it
> finishes its execution, and that a dependent instruction can (if
> selected) begin its execution in the cycle after that. The execution
> time of all instructions is two cycles, except for multiplication
> (which takes 4 cycles) and division (which takes 8 cycles). The
> processor has one multiply/divide unit and one add/subtract unit. The
> multiply/divide unit has two reservation stations and the add/subtract
> unit has four reservation stations. None of the execution units is
> pipelined â€“ each can only be executing one instruction at a time. If
> a conflict for the use of an execution unit occurs when selecting
> which instruction should start to execute, the older instruction (the
> one that appears earlier in program order) has priority. If a conflict
> for use of the CBD occurs, the result of the add/subtract unit has
> priority over the result of the multiply/divide unit. Assume that at
> start all instructions are already in the instruction queue, but none
> has yet been issued to any reservation stations. The processor can
> issue only one instruction per cycle, and there is only one CDB for
> writing results. A way of handling exceptions in the processor
> described above would be to simply delete all instructions from
> reservation stations and the instruction queue, set all RAT entries to
> point to the register file, and jump to the exception handler as soon
> as possible (i.e. in the cycle after the one in which divide-by-zero
> is detected). 1)Find the cycle time of each instruction for Issue,
> Exection, and Write back stages. 2)What would be printed in the
> exception handler if exceptions are handled this way?

---

provided solution:

> timing diagram
>
> [image]

solution for second question

> The exception occurs in cycle 20, so the cycle in which we start executing the exception handler
> is cycle 21. At that time, the processor has completed instructions I1-I4, but it has also completed
> instructions I6 and I10. As a result, register F4 in the register file would have the result of I10,
> which is -1 (5-6). The exception handler would print 2,0, -2, -1, which is incorrect.

Comment: Weren't there any paragraphs in the original problem?  That's quite a wall of text.

Comment: no @PeterCordes I just copied and pasted the problem as it appears in the course

Answer (score 1):

Is there a limited ROB or RS (scheduler) size that would stop the front-end from issuing more instructions until some have dispatched to make more room (RS size), or until some have retired (ROB size)?  It's common for the front-end's best case to be better throughput than the back-end, precisely so the back-end can get a look at possible independent instructions later on.  But there has to be some limit to how many un-executed instructions can be tracked by the back-end.

In this case, yes:

> The multiply/divide unit has two reservation stations and the add/subtract unit has four reservation stations

So I think that's the limiting factor there: the first two instructions are mul and div, and the first of those finishes on cycle 5.  Apparently this CPU doesn't free the RS entry until the cycle after writeback.  (And instead of one unified scheduler, it has queues (reservation stations) for each kind of execution unit separately.)

---

Some real CPUs may be more aggressive, e.g. I think Intel CPUs can free an RS entry sooner, even though they sometimes need to replay a uop if it was optimistically dispatched early in anticipation of a cache hit (when an input is the result of a load): [Are load ops deallocated from the RS when they dispatch, complete or some other time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59905395)